# Spring MVC Security Not Securing Views

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-security

The following example isn't correctly securing my views. The view are rendering and displaying they just aren't secured correctly.

The views live in WEB-INF/jsp and contain an Angular app with Angular Router.

I don't think that the Angular app nor the Router is the root cause so I haven't included them below. If they are, I will gladly supply the code.

I'm also using CustomUserDetailsService with H2, Data JPA, Hibernate, etc. I haven't included that since the main issue right now pertains to securing the routes as opposed to the actual authentication and persistence flow itself. Again, perhaps those items are incorrectly configured.

Any help is much appreciated! Thanks!

AppConfig:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
@ComponentScan()
public class AppConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {

    public void addViewControllers(ViewControllerRegistry registry) {
        registry.addViewController("/").setViewName("index");
        registry.addViewController("/login").setViewName("login");
        registry.addViewController("/secured/socket").setViewName("socket");
        registry.addViewController("/secured/success").setViewName("success");
        registry.addViewController("/denied").setViewName("denied");
    }

    @Bean
    public UrlBasedViewResolver viewResolver() {
        UrlBasedViewResolver resolver = new UrlBasedViewResolver();
        resolver.setPrefix("/WEB-INF/jsp/");
        resolver.setSuffix(".jsp");
        resolver.setViewClass(JstlView.class);
        return resolver;
    }

    @Override
    public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
        registry.addResourceHandler("/resources/**")
                .addResourceLocations("/", "/resources/")
                .setCachePeriod(3600)
                .resourceChain(true)
                .addResolver(new PathResourceResolver());
    }
}
```

SecurityConfig:

```
@Configuration
@EnableGlobalAuthentication
@ComponentScan
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
                .authorizeRequests()
                    .antMatchers("/").permitAll()
                    .antMatchers("/index").permitAll()
                    .antMatchers("/denied").permitAll()
                    .antMatchers("/authenticate").permitAll()
                    .antMatchers("/secured/socket").authenticated()
                    .antMatchers("/secured/success").authenticated()
                    .antMatchers("/secured/pet").authenticated()
                    .antMatchers("/secured/**/**").authenticated()
                    .anyRequest().authenticated()
                    .and()
                .formLogin()
                    .loginPage("/login").permitAll()
                    .usernameParameter("username").passwordParameter("password")
                    .loginProcessingUrl("/authenticate")
                    .defaultSuccessUrl("/secured/success",true)
                    //.failureUrl("/login.html?error=true")
                    .and()
                .logout()
                    .logoutSuccessUrl("/index").permitAll()
                    .and()
                .exceptionHandling()
                    .accessDeniedPage("/denied")
                    .and()
                .csrf();
    }
}
```

Edit: to help clarify the problem - the route `/secured/success` or `success.jsp` does not require authentication to be accessed or viewed. Neither do any of the other views specified above. They should.

Comment: So, and what the problem actually is? I've moved your `SecurityConfig` and its works for me.

Comment: I think I was very clear but let me clarify - with the above configuration, '/secured/success' - the 'success.jsp' - is exposed and accessible without authentication.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK,I think I solved this - the configuration files above are fine but I forgot to add the `springSecurityFilterChain` via:

```
public class SpringSecurityInitializer extends AbstractSecurityWebApplicationInitializer {
   //do nothing
}
```

as well as:

```
@Configuration
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true)
@EnableWebSecurity
@ComponentScan(//...)
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
//...
}
```

Apparently, though I might be mistaken in this, `@EnableWebSecurity` must be explicitly stated in order to trigger the use of `springSecurityFilterChain`.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you forgot `@EnableWebSecurity` annotation at `SecurityConfig`.

Comment: I have tried it with `@EnableWebSecurity` and several annotations that also annotate `@EnableWebSecurity` such `@EnableWebMvcSecurity` and `@EnableGlobalAuthentication` (which this should have been): https://spring.io/blog/2013/07/04/spring-security-java-config-preview-method-security/ - still, using those annotations does not resolve the problem.